# Steam game (DOS2) shows as uninstalled

Tags: steam, pc, divinity-original-sin-2

Recently bought Divinity: Original Sin 2 and have been experiencing an odd bug I haven't run into before with any games.

When I turn off my computer, when I turn it back on DOS2 appears as uninstalled on Steam. This doesn't happen EVERY time I turn it off, only sometimes.

The files are NOT uninstalled, however Steam doesn't recognize them until I try to "install" the game, at which point it discovers the already existing files. The same issue I'm experiencing is mentioned in this question 
[Should I be worried if Steam forgot I installed a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42225/should-i-be-worried-if-steam-forgot-i-installed-a-game) However no solution is presented.

Obviously this isn't the hugest issue as steam re-discovers the game when I hit install, but it does force a 5-10 minute wait before loading the game up while it's rediscovering the files. Why is this happening in the first place and how can I make it stop?

Game bought direct from steam, stored on internal HD.

Comment: Where did you buy it? directly from Steam? 3rd party provider? Local brick and mortar store?

Comment: What kind of hard drive or storage device is it on? An external one?

Answer (score 1):

If you shut down your computer too fast, steam sometimes corrupts certain files that help steam recognise that the game is installed. Those files are called app manifests. If you want to prevent this from happening, don't force turn off your computer (holding power button) and let steam finish closing. If the problem still continues after this, go to the games store page and remember the ID number at the top then close steam. Go to your steamapps directory and find the app_manifest with that number next to it. After you've done that find someone who already owns the game to copy their manifest, or find it online (the most recent one) and replace the text in the manifest file with theirs/ the one you found, and then save. Then open steam and it should be installed. Should take less than 5 minutes the second time.

Comment: I'm going to check if this works when I have time and if it does I'll accept this as an answer, given my computer habits (I force shut-down frequently) I'm pretty confident this will be the solution